# How to extend AxisX display range when using WaveformGraph PlotYAppend

Tags: measurement-studio

I am using National Instruments WaveformGraph control with PlotYAppend function to display stream of data coming from external DAQ board.

By default WaveformGraph show only 1000 points from appended array, how is possible to change that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the properties of the waveform graph is history capacity. The default is 1000.

```
    Me.WaveformGraph1.Plots(0).HistoryCapacity = 5000
```